# how to extract request body from post request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I set up a servet socket and post requests arrive there. I get everything at once in one line. Json is passed to the post request. How can I get this json separately?

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs


import socket

SERVER_HOST = ''
SERVER_PORT = 8080

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)
print('Listening on port %s ...' % SERVER_PORT)

while True:    
    client_connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()

    data = client_connection.recv(1024).decode()
    
    print(data)


server_socket.close()
```

Comment: POST is defined in HTTP. Using socket you will get raw binary payload and you need to process it by yourself. Server you have created is a TCP server not an HTTP which is something on top of TCP server. Either build a request parser or change the server nature to cope with the HTTP.

Comment: is there an example request parser?

Comment: Sure I just tried with Google and the first hit was a good one. https://pypi.org/project/http-parser/